# Error in ebay integration - "21916250 : Return policy is not specified. A return policy must be specified."

Tags: php, ebay-api

I want to develop a system like exporting products from my site to ebay site. I created developer account and got sample code for adding products to ebay. I got PHP sample code from https://www.x.com/developers/eBay/documentation-tools/code-sample/219177 . I added sandbox API details in the sample code and when I run the code I get this error :

```
eBay returned the following error(s):

21916250 : Return policy is not specified.
A return policy must be specified.
```

I am new to ebay integration? How can I specify Return policy in ebay sample code. I am am adding sample code for your reference:

```
<?php require_once('../get-common/keys.php') ?>
<?php require_once('../get-common/eBaySession.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>AddItem</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM action="AddItem.php" method="post">
<TABLE cellpadding="2" border="0">
    <TR>
        <TD>listingType</TD>
        <TD>
          <select name="listingType">
            <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
            <option value="Dutch">Dutch</option>
            <option value="FixedPriceItem">Fixed Price Item</option>
            <option value="StoresFixedPrice">Stores Fixed Price</option>
          </select>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>primaryCategory</TD>
        <TD>
          <select name="primaryCategory">
        <option value="14111">Test Category</option>
            <option value="57889">Boys Athletic Pants</option>
            <option value="57890">Boys Corduroys Pants</option>
            <option value="57891">Boys Jeans Pants</option>
            <option value="57892">Boys Khakis Pants</option>
          </select>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>itemTitle</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="itemTitle" value="TEST IN SANDBOX BEFORE PROD - DO NOT BID" size=30></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>itemDescription</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="itemDescription" value="TEST IN SANDBOX BEFORE PROD - DO NOT BID - This will incur prod listing fees" size=30></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>listingDuration</TD>
        <TD>
          <select name="listingDuration">
            <option value="Days_1">1 day</option>
            <option value="Days_3">3 days</option>
            <option value="Days_5">5 days</option>
            <option value="Days_7">7 days</option>
          </select>
          (defaults to GTC = 30 days for Store)
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>startPrice</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="startPrice" value="<?php echo rand(1,200) / 100 ?>"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>buyItNowPrice</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="buyItNowPrice" value="<?php echo rand(299,599) / 100; ?>"> (set to 0.0 for Store)</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>quantity</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="quantity" value="1"> (must be 1 for Chinese)</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan="2" align="right"><INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="AddItem"></TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['listingType']))
    {
        ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', false);    // magic quotes will only confuse things like escaping apostrophe
        //Get the item entered
        $listingType     = $_POST['listingType'];
        $primaryCategory = $_POST['primaryCategory'];
        $itemTitle       = $_POST['itemTitle'];
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            // print "stripslashes!!! <br>\n";
            $itemDescription = stripslashes($_POST['itemDescription']);
        } else {
            $itemDescription = $_POST['itemDescription'];
        }
        $itemDescription = $_POST['itemDescription'];
        $listingDuration = $_POST['listingDuration'];
        $startPrice      = $_POST['startPrice'];
        $buyItNowPrice   = $_POST['buyItNowPrice'];
        $quantity        = $_POST['quantity'];

        if ($listingType == 'StoresFixedPrice') {
          $buyItNowPrice = 0.0;   // don't have BuyItNow for SIF
          $listingDuration = 'GTC';
        }

        if ($listingType == 'Dutch') {
          $buyItNowPrice = 0.0;   // don't have BuyItNow for Dutch
        }

        //SiteID must also be set in the Request's XML
        //SiteID = 0  (US) - UK = 3, Canada = 2, Australia = 15, ....
        //SiteID Indicates the eBay site to associate the call with
        $siteID = 0;
        //the call being made:
        $verb = 'AddItem';

        ///Build the request Xml string
        $requestXmlBody  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
        $requestXmlBody .= '<AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
        $requestXmlBody .= "<RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>$userToken</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>";
        $requestXmlBody .= '<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>';
        $requestXmlBody .= '<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>';
        $requestXmlBody .= "<Version>$compatabilityLevel</Version>";
        $requestXmlBody .= '<Item>';
        $requestXmlBody .= '<Site>US</Site>';
        $requestXmlBody .= '<PrimaryCategory>';
        $requestXmlBody .= "<CategoryID>$primaryCategory</CategoryID>";
        $requestXmlBody .= '</PrimaryCategory>';
        $requestXmlBody .= "<BuyItNowPrice currencyID=\"USD\">$buyItNowPrice</BuyItNowPrice>";
        $requestXmlBody .= '<Country>US</Country>';
        $requestXmlBody .= '<Currency>USD</Currency>';
        $requestXmlBody .= "<ListingDuration>$listingDuration</ListingDuration>";
        $requestXmlBody .= "<ListingType>$listingType</ListingType>";
        $requestXmlBody .= '<Location><![CDATA[San Jose, CA]]></Location>';
        $requestXmlBody .= '<PaymentMethods>PaymentSeeDescription</PaymentMethods>';
        $requestXmlBody .= "<Quantity>$quantity</Quantity>";
        $requestXmlBody .= '<RegionID>0</RegionID>';
        $requestXmlBody .= "<StartPrice>$startPrice</StartPrice>";
        $requestXmlBody .= '<ShippingTermsInDescription>True</ShippingTermsInDescription>';
        $requestXmlBody .= "<Title><![CDATA[$itemTitle]]></Title>";
        $requestXmlBody .= "<Description><![CDATA[$itemDescription]]></Description>";
        $requestXmlBody .= '</Item>';
        $requestXmlBody .= '</AddItemRequest>';

        //Create a new eBay session with all details pulled in from included keys.php
        $session = new eBaySession($userToken, $devID, $appID, $certID, $serverUrl, $compatabilityLevel, $siteID, $verb);

        //send the request and get response
        $responseXml = $session->sendHttpRequest($requestXmlBody);
        if(stristr($responseXml, 'HTTP 404') || $responseXml == '')
            die('<P>Error sending request');

        //Xml string is parsed and creates a DOM Document object
        $responseDoc = new DomDocument();
        $responseDoc->loadXML($responseXml);

        //get any error nodes
        $errors = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Errors');

        //if there are error nodes
        if($errors->length > 0)
        {
            echo '<P><B>eBay returned the following error(s):</B>';
            //display each error
            //Get error code, ShortMesaage and LongMessage
            $code     = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ErrorCode');
            $shortMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ShortMessage');
            $longMsg  = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('LongMessage');
            //Display code and shortmessage
            echo '<P>', $code->item(0)->nodeValue, ' : ', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $shortMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));
            //if there is a long message (ie ErrorLevel=1), display it
            if(count($longMsg) > 0)
                echo '<BR>', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $longMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));

        } else { //no errors

            //get results nodes
            $responses = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName("AddItemResponse");
            foreach ($responses as $response) {
              $acks = $response->getElementsByTagName("Ack");
              $ack   = $acks->item(0)->nodeValue;
              echo "Ack = $ack <BR />\n";   // Success if successful

              $endTimes  = $response->getElementsByTagName("EndTime");
              $endTime   = $endTimes->item(0)->nodeValue;
              echo "endTime = $endTime <BR />\n";

              $itemIDs  = $response->getElementsByTagName("ItemID");
              $itemID   = $itemIDs->item(0)->nodeValue;
              echo "itemID = $itemID <BR />\n";

              $linkBase = "http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=";
              echo "<a href=$linkBase" . $itemID . ">$itemTitle</a> <BR />";

              $feeNodes = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Fee');
              foreach($feeNodes as $feeNode) {
                $feeNames = $feeNode->getElementsByTagName("Name");
                if ($feeNames->item(0)) {
                    $feeName = $feeNames->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    $fees = $feeNode->getElementsByTagName('Fee');  // get Fee amount nested in Fee
                    $fee = $fees->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    if ($fee > 0.0) {
                        if ($feeName == 'ListingFee') {
                          printf("<B>$feeName : %.2f </B><BR>\n", $fee); 
                        } else {
                          printf("$feeName : %.2f <BR>\n", $fee);
                        }      
                    }  // if $fee > 0
                } // if feeName
              } // foreach $feeNode

            } // foreach response

        } // if $errors->length > 0
    }
?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Specify a return policy.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I hereby award you the John Cleese hat, a special hat that you deserve for your uncanny ability to state the bleedin' obvious :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ignacio said, just add a `ReturnPolicy` tag after the `Description` tag, for example something like this:

```
<ReturnPolicy>
    <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_14</ReturnsWithinOption>
    <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
    <Description>ReturnPolicy text</Description>
    <WarrantyDurationOption>Years_2</WarrantyDurationOption>
    <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Seller</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
</ReturnPolicy>
```